# How to do validation using mvvmcross

Tags: validation, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have just started learning to write mobile apps using Xamarin and MvvmCross. I have found it quite easy to pick up the basics due to the great support including the N+1 days of MvvmCross videos on YouTube (Huge thanks to Stuart Lodge).

However I am struggling with valudation data. I'm hoping someone on Stackoverflow can point me in the direction of some useful blogs or tutorials on performing validation using MvvmCross. I want to be able validate the data entered and then update the view indicating the issue.

I need something from first principles as I don't know what I don't know (If that makes sense). I need some best practice to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Data validation can be displayed in the UI in different ways.
For example, you can show a message box or show a label.

Suppose you want to have a label with red text somewhere in the UI to show the error.

I assume you have a 'Save' button or similar in your UI.

You can bind the button to a `SaveCommand` in the view-model.

In the implementation of the `SaveCommand`, you can check if all the data is valid and set an `Error` string property.

You can have a label's text bound to the `Error` property. Moreover, you could also bind the label's visibility to the condition (Error != null).

```
public class SettingsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
     string firstName;
     public string FirstName
     {
           get { return this.firstName; }
           set 
           { 
              if(this.firstName != value) 
              { 
                   this.firstName = value;
                   this.RaisePropertyChanged(()=> this.FirstName);
                   this.Error = null; // reset error
              }
          }
     }

     public string Error { get; private set; }

     public ICommand SaveCommand { get { return new MvxCommand(this.Save); } }

     void Save()
     {
         // reset error
         this.Error = null; 

         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName))
         {
             this.Error = "First name is empty";
         }

         if(string.IsNullOrEmtpy(this.Error))
         {
              // no error, save settings...
         } 
         else
         {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(()=> this.Error);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but I was looking for a framework to do it rather than rolling my own. I should have been clearer in my original question.  Is there anything built into MvvmCross. I looked at the validation plugin, but there was no examples of how you use it.

Comment: I did Google it (I did laugh!), it's just there are no examples of how to use it that I understand.

Comment: there's a demo included